# sed: problem while replacing string using wildcard

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to replace a string using the following command:

```
sed -e "s/\<$5\>/$6/g" "$2/$1" > "$4/$3"

$5-> "hostname=*"
$6-> "hostname=int1"
$2/$1-> "source file path"
$4/$3-> "destination file path"
```

When I try to replace the following:

```
hostname=abc
```

I get,

```
hostname=int1=abc
```

But I want,

```
hostname=int1
```

How can I match string to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide part of the source file you want to manage

Comment: This looks suspiciously like XML source. Is it?

Comment: Yes, this is part of the same script but not related to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` uses regular expressions.  These are different from patterns ("globs") that the shell uses.

Notice that the following doesn't work:

```
$ echo hostname=abc | sed "s/\<hostname=*\>/hostname=int1/"
hostname=int1=abc
```

But, the following does:

```
$ echo hostname=abc | sed "s/\<hostname=.*\>/hostname=int1/"
hostname=int1
```

You need a `.` before the `*`.

*As a regular expression*, `hostname=*` means `hostname` followed by zero or more equal signs.  Thus `sed "s/\<hostname=*\>/hostname=int1/"` replaces `hostname` with `hostname=int1`.

By contrast, the regular expression `hostname=.*` means `hostname=` followed by zero or more any character at all.  That is why `s/\<hostname=.*\>/hostname=int1/` replaces `hostname=abc` with `hostname=int1`.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better solution than this but you can use the below command.

`sed /hostname.*$/s//"hostname=int1"/g /home/path/of/your/original/file > /tmp/hello.$$`

`cat /tmp/hello.$$  >  /home/path/of/your/original/file`